# Updating JList when elements are added froma different Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel, jlist

I have a problem with an application
I use netbeans GUI BUilder 
I havea jList that contains elements I added element to this JList,
My program have two tabs, the first tab contain a jpanel that contains the Jlist and the second tab contain Another Jpanel.
I want to add element to the Jlist from the second Tab, The add is successful nut when I swith to the first Tab that Contains the Jlist the elements added are not therethe only element that the Jlist contains are the elements I added from the begining.

There is no problems we the add method everything is fine, My question is how do I update my jList when I add elements from anoother JPanel

Answer (score 0):

When adding elements, make sure they are added to the list model. Then call fireContentsChanged().